# NPM install always fails with JSON parse & file not found in .staging folder

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Npm install is failing for me with

1. json parse exception (everytime at different location)
2. file not found in .staging warning

I am on node: 12.18.3, npm: 6.14.6
for my other team mates it works fine

I tried

Node & npm reinstall

Tried with nvm also

Npm cache clean –force

Deleted node_modules

Deleted package-lock json

Also increased the size of buffer

http.postbuffer=524288000

http.maxrequestbuffer=100M

LOGS

IN-GN-52242:ui amar.tangade$ npm install

> cloud preinstall /Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui
> node tasks/check-install.js

x---------------------------------------WARNING---------------------------------------x
Cloud ui should be checked out at "/Users/amar.tangade/g/cloud/ui"
x-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------x

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@angular/animations-d4575e16/bundles/animations.umd.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata-28cad3f5/chinaLow.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/bootstrap-d6314d99/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata-28cad3f5/chinaLow.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@sentry/tracing-103892ec/build/bundle.tracing.min.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/fontkit-a9ca368f/src/opentype/shapers/data.trie'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/fontkit-a9ca368f/src/opentype/shapers/indic.trie'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/fontkit-a9ca368f/src/opentype/shapers/use.trie'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@angular/upgrade-74767da7/esm2015/static/src/downgrade_module.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/svg-to-pdfkit-a3211ec1/examples/demo.htm'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@angular/animations-d4575e16/fesm2015/browser.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@angular/cdk-8525faf0/bundles/cdk-overlay.umd.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/pdfmake-0c446f39/src/browser-extensions'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/pdfmake-0c446f39/build/pdfmake.min.js'
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ecterm**](http://elec'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap-802705fe/esm2015/modal/modal-dismiss-reasons.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap-802705fe/esm2015/modal/modal-ref.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap-802705fe/esm2015/modal/modal-stack.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/CONTRIBUTING.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/DEVELOPER.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/exampleTypescript/asyncAwait/README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/exampleTypescript/README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/exampleTypescript/angularPage.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/built/driverProviders/attachSession.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/built/bpRunner.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/built/browser.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/built/driverProviders/browserStack.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/built/cli.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/exampleTypescript/conf.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar.tangade/Desktop/cloud/ui/node_modules/.staging/protractor-646a0f46/built/config.d.ts'

Comment: can you add the stack error?

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded npm version to 6.14.5 and it worked for me.